# AMD Threadripper support

Tags: amd

Does current eOS build work with Ryzen specifically Thraeadripper 1950? Or do I need to do some specific steps to build to latest kernel?

Answer (score 1):

[image]

can confirm that it does infact work with a 1950 threadripper